# Missing Multiple Blending Options

Tags: photoshop-effects, blending

I recently uninstalled and reinstalled photoshop from the creative cloud and now half my blending options are disabled.  I tried the solution from the 4-year-old topic of resetting them to the default, but it did not make them light up.

Any other suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Check the image mode of the file you are editing. Some of Photoshop's functionality is disabled in various image modes (32bit, 16bit, CMYK, Lab), this includes some filters and layer blending modes. Reinstalling the software won't fix this. If you want everything to work choose RGB and 8bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are working in *32-Bits/Channel* mode where some of the blending modes don't work.

In *Image > Mode*, change to either *16-Bits/Channel* or *8-Bits/Channel*.

[image]

Comment: There's my ignorance at work lol, I thought, more bits = better.  I changed it and now it works.  Thank you!